# Decorator Function makes data reading return nonetype

Tags: python, pandas, python-decorators

I've written a pretty simple `timetaken()` decorator function which naturally measures how long it takes for a function to run:

```
def timetaken(func):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    before = time.time()
    func(*args, **kwargs)
    print(f"Function took {time.time() - before} seconds")
  return wrapper
```

I run a test of it on a function that reads in data shown below:

```
@timetaken
def ingest(filename):
  if filename.endswith(".csv") and searcher('winequality-red.csv', ',') == True:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
  elif filename.endswith('.csv') and \
        searcher('winequality-red.csv', ';') == True:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ";")
  elif filename.endswith(".xlsx") or filename.endswith(".xlx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
  elif filename.endswith('.com') or filename.endswith('.html'):
    df = pd.read_html(filename)
  elif filename.endswith('.txt'):
    df = pd.read_txt(filename)
  else:
    print('File could not be read!')
    return -1
  return df
```

The `searcher()` function, simply locates string characters in a file.

Anyway, when I remove the decorator, the function works as expected and returns a pandas Dataframe object. However, with the decorator, it simply returns `NoneType`. Does anyone know why this may be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this decorator to return the return value:

```py
def timetaken(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        before = time.time()
        ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"Function took {time.time() - before} seconds")
        return ret
    return wrapper
```